# How to define a procedure that returns multiple values in R7RS

Tags: scheme, r7rs

TL;DR: How to define a procedure `foobar` which can be used as `(let-values ((foo bar) (foobar)) ...)`.

---

R7RS defines two procedures `floor/` and `truncate`, which computes the quotient **and** remainder of two numbers divided. I find this really tricky because I can only use these procedures with `let-values` (or `let*-values`). A more important issue is that I cannot find a way to define my own procedures that returns multiple values.

Does someone have any ideas?

Note:

- The definitions of `floor/` and `truncate/` are on the top of page 37 of [the report](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf).
- I'm not lucky enough to successfully install any R7RS-compliant interpreters or compilers, so I haven't tested any of the above ideas yet. When I had the opportunity I would update this question, if needed.

Comment: This feature hasn't changed since it got introduced in R5RS. Thus you will not find it under language changes in the R7RS.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [`values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._values%29%29)? [The report](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) mentions it on page 53.

```
(define (foobar)
  (values 1 2))

(let-values (((foo bar) (foobar)))
  (cons foo bar))
```

Comment: I did not notice this possible use of `values` when I first read it... That's what I want. Thanks a lot.